# How do I remove first 2 characters of each even numbered line?

Tags: cut-copy-paste

Suppose, I have

```
abcd
efgh
ijkl
mnop
qrst
```

I want to delete the first 2 character of each even numbered line.

```
abcd
gh
ijkl
op
qrst
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use `sed` to do this:

```
sed 'n;s/..//' file.txt > output.txt
```

Or inside of Vim via:

```
:%!sed 'n;s/..//'
```

A native solution in Vim can be accomplished with a sub-replace-expression

```
:%s/../\=line('.')%2==0?'':submatch(0)/
```

This works by replacing the first 2 character each line with either itself for odd lines or nothing for even lines.

For more help see:

```
:h :range!
:h :s
:h sub-replace-expression
:h line()
:h submatch()
```

Comment: +1 for the sed solution! BTW: `:%!sed '2~2s/..//'` (only GNU)

Answer (score 3):

Another native Vim command line solution:

```
:g/^../ if line(".") % 2 == 0 | s///
```

Pretty straightforward. The `g`lobal command takes us to every line in the file that has at least two characters. Check modulo 2 of the current line number returned by `line(".")` and if it indicates an even line then substitute nothing for the first two characters. We don't have to specify a pattern with the substitution command as it defaults to the last search term, i.e. `^..`.

If you like compact this version is nice and short...about 10 chars shorter than the other native c/l solution posted here. ;)

```
:g/^../if line(".")%2==0|s///
```

Answer (score 2):

You can record a recursive macro and run it from the start of the file as macros
stop when some action cannot be performed. In this case, it would be something
like this:

```
qqqqqj$xxj@qq@q
```

Edit: Should use ^ instead of $ to delete from the start of line.

Now, by parts:

```
qqq   -  Start and immediately end recording of register "q". This is only
         needed in recursive macros.

qq    -  Start recording in register q

j$xxj -  One line down, end of line, delete two characters and down again

@q    -  Run the contents of the macro @q (empty for now)

q     -  End recording of macro

@q    -  Run the contents of @q (not empty anymore)
```

Comment: A small correction - The question asked to delete the **first** 2 characters. For this,  we need to replace the `$` (line-end character) with `^` (line-start character). We can also leave out the `^` character altogether, coz the cursor is already at the line-start in the beginning as well as when it goes one line down each time. So we can use `qqqqqj^xxj@qq@q` or`qqqqqjxxj@qq@q`.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion

```
:g/./if line('.') % 2 == 0 | normal! xx
```